Understanding the Implications of Similar Smooth Functions in Generalised Additive Models
I have a question about GAM models.
If I fit two GAM models, one including all variables together and the other adding one variable at a time, and the resulting smooth functions are similar, what does this imply?
In order to be very clear, I provide an example:
Suppose we are analyzing the effect of temperature, humidity, and wind speed on energy consumption using Generalized Additive Models (GAMs). I decide to fit two models:
Model A: I include all predictors (temperature, humidity, and wind speed) simultaneously.
Model B: I fit multiple models with one predictor at a time, so you can observe the effect of each variable's smooth function separately.
If the smooth functions for a predictor (e.g. humidity) look very similar between Model A and the individual models in Model B, what does this suggest?
I think that there is:
Independence among variables: The independent variables are not strongly correlated with each other, so each one explains a distinct part of the variation in the dependent variable. As a result, the contribution of each variable is represented similarly in both types of models, without being affected by the presence or absence of other variables.
Low degree of collinearity: Low collinearity means that the variables do not overlap much in terms of the information they bring to the model. This allows each variable to maintain a stable contribution within the model, and the smoothing function associated with each variable does not change significantly when other variables are included or excluded.
Is it correct?
